# Android studio 3.1 not recognizing jar annotation processing

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I'm trying to implement my own annotation processor in my android studio project. All is working well and compiling until I add this simple line to build.gradle dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
   .
   .
   .
   annotationProcessor(':processor')
}
```

At that point I get this error when compiling:

> Could not find :processor:. Required by:
>       project :app Search in build.gradle files

I've followed endless tutorials and nothing seems to help. I've just recently upgraded to AS 3.1 and thinking maybe it relates?

Here is the project structure: (mind you - here I add the annotation processor as a jar file. I've also attached an image trying to do it as a different module and same result)

[image]

Here is a different I'm trying to add it - creating the annotation processor in the same project with a different module and still no go:

[image]

Some extra info in pics...
Project structure:

[image]

app.build:

[image]

processor.build:

[image]

annotation:

[image]

MainActivity:

[image]

Processor implementation:

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it does not look like there is a `processor` directory anywhere in your project. Where is the subproject source code stored? You are supposed to place the source code within the gradle project tree, otherwise the `':subprojectname'` dependencies won't work.

Comment: My processor is a jar artifact which I created in a different project. It's not inside a submodule

Comment: Then remove `annotationProcessor(':processor')` line. Use `annotationProcessor` to declare *another* dependency on `libs/processor.jar`. I assume, that your jar contains both annotations/libraries and processor, doesn't it? In that case having to declare two dependencies (`annotationProcessor` and `implementation` or `annotationProcessor` and `compileOnly`) on the same artifact is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Can you show an example of the syntax please?

Comment: I've added an image with a different attempt - the processor implemented as a module and still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have everything inside the same artifact, — annotation processor, it's annotations and library classes, used by processor users, Android Gradle plugin requires you to declare *two* dependencies on the same artifact:

```
annotationProcessor project(':processor')
compile project(':processor')
```

or

```
annotationProcessor files('libs/processor.jar')
compile files('libs/processor.jar')
```

Note, that such setup might become unsupported in future. It is advisable to split your processor in separate module and make it depend on the rest of code. After doing so you will be able to declare dependencies like this:

```
annotationProcessor project(':processor') // processor-only jar
compile project(':processor-api') // annotations and classes for user code
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - now I can compile the projects! Now it seems that although it compiles fine - the processor is never invoked. I've edited my question adding extra pictures for project structure and the processor implementation and such. Would love your help.

Comment: @Yosi199 You haven't posted contents of `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`. Do they point to the correct class name? Also printing to `System.out` isn't necessarily going to do anything. Remember, that Gradle runs compilation in Gradle's *daemon*  process, which might simply redirect it's stdout to /dev/null. If you want to log something from processor, use `Messenger`

Comment: Thanks that was pretty much the case - after it compiled successfully I couldn't see any output but I was looking in the wrong place. My bad.